# Implementing a simple GET method in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to create a simple Spring project with a GET method and am having trouble allowing access to it. Here is my controller...

```
package controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController;

public class IndexController extends AbstractController {

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1) throws Exception {
        String message = "Hello, World!";
        return new ModelAndView("index", "msg", message);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView setupForm(@RequestParam("name") String name) {
        return new ModelAndView("index", "msg", name);
    }
}
```

When I type the URL: 'http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld/index.htm?name=jon' for example, it simply returns the top method. Any ideas?

Many thanks,
J

Comment: Did you try not extending any class. Annotating @Controller and removing the overridden method.

Comment: When I did that and ran it with the url <etc>/HelloWorld/index.htm, it gives me the error:  The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect ().

Comment: @Jon that usually means that you're missing request parameters.

Comment: Also I don't see the url mapping in the controller. Have you done it elsewhere?

Comment: @soulcheck I have the request paramters set in the GET method don't I?
My mappings are in dispatcher-servlet.xml:
<bean name="indexController" class="controller.IndexController"/>

Comment: @Jon you do have it in mapping, but the request you send (probably) doesn't have the necessary parameter. Usually it's a typo. Check the request in firebug or chrome inspector.

Comment: Surely if it gets to the controller fine, but goes to the wrong method it has to be this GET method of mine? I am not entirely sure how it finds this method but from my experience (little as it is) I assumed Spring finds the method matching the url and uses that. So if it ends with '?name=', it would choose the method with that @RequestParam matches?

Comment: @Jon no, `@RequestParam` isn't used for matching, just for parameter binding. If you want to match by params you have to add `params` attribute of `@RequestMapping`. So in your case it would be `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, params = "name")`

Comment: Yeah I tried that:
    @RequestMapping(value = "index.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET, params = {"name"})
    public ModelAndView handleBasicGet(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam("name") String name) {
        return new ModelAndView("index", "msg", name);
    }
But it still goes to the top method. Perhaps its a problem with the dispatcher or applicationContext xml files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try getting rid of AbstractController (don't extend it) and follow the advice given by Petter (btw, it's better to add @RequestMapping to both methods). Instead, mark the controller with @Controller annotation. After that it should work.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much, getting rid of AbstractController, adding @Controller and adding '@RequestMappings' to both worked! I am not really sure why though, because it worked the other way at work somehow =P Thanks to everyone else who had some excellent ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Add a request mapping to your method to mapp it to some specific url under your applications root url

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/something")
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that. It still goes to the top method. I am not sure if there is a broken link with the files somewhere, does the jsp file need to have any addition code to link to this method at all?